# How to edit inline buttons with text ? telegram bot, telegraf, node

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, telegram, telegraf

I'm using the telegraf library to create my own bot.

I just want to edit a message which has buttons.

I have this:

[image: button img]

After clicking on 30 or 31 it adds a plus symbol and it looks like this:

[image: button img2]

It works like this: I send a message, the user pushes a button, the message is deleted, and it shows the new message with the added plus.

I just want to do it without deleting the message and sending a new one, i.e. using the edit function, but I can't find it.

`editMessageText` is not what I need, its just changing to text and the buttons are missing.

Answer (score 2):

digging Telegraf documentation you would have come up with this API:

https://telegraf.js.org/#/?id=editmessagereplymarkup

which can be used in this pattern:

```
telegram.editMessageReplyMarkup(chatId, messageId, inlineMessageId, markup, [extra]) => Promise
```